# Add JTable dynamically

Tags: java, swing, dynamic, jtable

I have here the code when a button is clicked. It is supposed to add a `JTable` in the `JPanel regularPanel`. The problem is that it doesn't show in the panel.

I added the panel in the frame via clicking the panel component.

```
    String[] columnNames = {"First Name",
                            "Last Name",
                            "Sport",
                            "# of Years",
                            "Vegetarian"};

    Object[][] data = {
        {"Kathy", "Smith",
         "Snowboarding", new Integer(5), new Boolean(false)},
        {"John", "Doe",
         "Rowing", new Integer(3), new Boolean(true)},
        {"Sue", "Black",
         "Knitting", new Integer(2), new Boolean(false)},
        {"Jane", "White",
         "Speed reading", new Integer(20), new Boolean(true)},
        {"Joe", "Brown",
         "Pool", new Integer(10), new Boolean(false)}
    };
    JTable table = new JTable(data,columnNames);
    table.setBounds(100, 100, 100, 80);
    JScrollPane tableContainer = new JScrollPane(table);
    regularPanel.add(tableContainer);
```

What should I do to view that table in the panel?

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example). 2) I would approach this by adding the `JTable` from the start, but *populating the table model* on button click. 3) `table.setBounds(100, 100, 100, 80);` Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  ..

Comment: .. Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).

Comment: what problem are you facing exactly ? is there any error message ?

Comment: The problem is that I cant see the table in the panel after clicking the button

Comment: Did you try `revalidate()` and `repaint()`?

Comment: did you see it after resizing the Frame ? @CrazyGirl

Comment: revalidate and repaint didnt do it. @Blip

Comment: nope. didnt see it. @AlokMishra

Comment: is your `regularPanel` an instance of `JPanel`?

Comment: Yes, it is a jpanel. @Blip

Comment: could you post the code related to the `regularPanel`?

Comment: Please show little more code , i am still not able to get what problem you are facing . i have run your code in my eclipse and it ran successfully and the table is shown . i need to to know how you are handling the button click event .

Answer (score 0):

Add your table to the `JScrollPane` viewport.

Try the following:

```
TableModel tableDataModel = new AbstractTableModel() {
    public int getColumnCount() { return 2; }
    public int getRowCount() { return 5; }
    public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) { return new Integer(row*col); }
JTable table = new JTable(tableDataModel);
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
scrollPane.getViewport().add(table);
```

In your button event handler, you should also be sure to call `revalidate()` and potentially `repaint()` once the table container is added to your panel.